# How to access files shared via OneDrive `direct access` mode?

Tags: onedrive

OneDrive allows 2 ways to share files/folders:

1. Link sharing
2. Direct access

When someone shares a file with me with option 1 (link sharing), then I need to have the link to access the file.

This question is to ask - when a file is shared with me using option 2 (direct access), then how do I access the file?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The other user has also to be logged in into OneDrive/office.com.

In the left navigation pane under "My Content" is a menu point "Shared", there the user will see all files that were shared with him via direct access.

[Example screenshot with UI in German language.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqbSa.png)

Comment: But the files listed on that page can be `Removed from shared list` (by clicking on ellipses on the shared file) - then in that case how can I reach the list of files/folders?

Comment: It's not possible according to https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-undo-remove-from-shared-list/0e7c32e2-1d38-4b4e-a06f-f788ccf80e9f, so one would have to search for the e-mails with notification about the shared document. And if those are gone too, there seems to be no way.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Microsoft 365 Apps?

If yes, you can go to Excel > Open > **Shared with me**, check whether the file is listed.

Besides, after someone has shared files with you from OneDrive, there should be an email notification showing the name of the folder or file. I suggest you try to search this email.

If nothing helps, and it is inconvenient to find the previous person to share again, please find a colleague who has permission access to this file to share it with you.